# Problem with hitting the breakpoints in JavaScript libraries in DevTools

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need to Debug the javascript libraries(in this case KendoUI sourcefile) in Chrome DevTools, I've put some breakpoints in either its minified and prettified file but normally the breakpoints won't hit despite the codes are executing.

I also used `debugger` in the demanded function but still it does not enter the debug mode.
I tried the event listener breakpoints, with this approach the jquery library has gone to debug mode but again when I step over next function (F10 key) the debugger will never enter the KendoUi sourcefile and still none of the breakpoints works automatically.

=> the point is when I Step Into (F9 key) the codes and follow the flow step by step it will lead to reach the kendoUI sourcefile and the mentioned function can be debugged.

**the problem is that takes too much time to follow the whole flow every time.

```
 //this is the function in kendoUI that I need to debug.

_unselect: function(e) {
            debugger;
            return e.removeClass(d),
            this.options.aria && e.attr(l, !1),
            e
        }
```

I need to find a way to Directly debug a special line of code in KendoUi or any other js library using a breakpoint instead of stepping into all that happens before it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Press `F8` instead of `F10`. It will directly reach `debugger` given `_unselect` gets called

Comment: I haven't used it a whole lot but you can check out the [Telerik Kendo UI Chrome Inspector](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/say-hello-to-the-kendo-ui-chrome-inspector) extension for chrome that might help.

Comment: the problem is I work remotely on a server and I haven't the permission to install anything on it, by the way thanks to you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such an issue many times and my workaround for this is like below.

Keep using F9 key till you reach to `_unselect` then put breakpoint there and refresh the page and see if it comes there or not. I have seen such issue with many libraries because of some misunderstanding of their code-flow there.

Hope these steps help.

Comment: I've done this before but unfortunately it doesn't work. the breakpoints don't hit, the debugger just skips them.